# Confusing syntax from a search tree algorithm

Tags: python

I am currently taking 6.00.2x from MITx, and there is a line from a search tree algorithm that confuses me, could anyone help please?

```
val, taken = maxVal(foods, maxUnits)
```

This syntax does not make sense to me. `maxVal` is a function, so presumably `foods` and `maxUnits` are inputs. But what are `val` and `taken`, what does this line do? Nowhere in the code are there variables instantiated with those names, so I am just not sure what they are (and this line of syntax means).

PS: The complete code is as follows. The aforementioned syntax occurs on 3rd line of the function `testMaxVal`. `foods` is a list of 1) food, 2) values, and 3) calories.

```
def maxVal(toConsider, avail):
    """Assumes toConsider a list of items, avail a weight
       Returns a tuple of the total value of a solution to the
         0/1 knapsack problem and the items of that solution"""
    if toConsider == [] or avail == 0:
        result = (0, ())
    elif toConsider[0].getCost() > avail:
        #Explore right branch only
        result = maxVal(toConsider[1:], avail)
    else:
        nextItem = toConsider[0]
        #Explore left branch
        withVal, withToTake = maxVal(toConsider[1:],
                                     avail - nextItem.getCost())
        withVal += nextItem.getValue()
        #Explore right branch
        withoutVal, withoutToTake = maxVal(toConsider[1:], avail)
        #Choose better branch
        if withVal > withoutVal:
            result = (withVal, withToTake + (nextItem,))
        else:
            result = (withoutVal, withoutToTake)
    return result

def testMaxVal(foods, maxUnits, printItems = True):
    print('Use search tree to allocate', maxUnits,
          'calories')
    val, taken = maxVal(foods, maxUnits)
    print('Total value of items taken =', val)
    if printItems:
        for item in taken:
            print('   ', item)

testMaxVal(foods, 750)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see,  maxVal can return two outputs at the same time like at the line :

```
result = (withoutVal, withoutToTake)
```

Recover these two outputs in two variable *val* and *taken* is done by the line :

```
val, taken = maxVal(foods, maxUnits)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `maxVal` returns a `tuple`. You can return multiple values from a function in python in the form of `tuple`.

Example:

```
def connect():
    connection = _connect()
    message = "Connected"
    if not connection:
        message = "Not connected"
    return connection, message

connection, message = connect()
```

Answer (score 1):

`maxVal` returns a pair.
You can "deconstruct" any tuple by assigning its elements to the appropriate number of variables simultaneously.

Example:

```
>>> a,b,c = (1,2, "hello")
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
'hello'
```